# Is this HVAC capacitor dead?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, central-air

HVAC system stopped blowing cold air today. Last time it did this, we gave it a 2-3 hour break, in case it was over-heated, and it came back. Today, same deal, but no cold air after a few hours. I went out and didn't hear the compressor or fan going.

After opening the unit to have a look, I noticed that 1) the capacitor had "goop" over it (see circled sections of pictures below) 2) the electronics "bay" looked a bit wet, which was odd (see top of picture #1 below). I suspect this is a sign of a blown capacitor, but GoogleBing image searches aren't conclusive. Suggestions? Opinions? Conclusions?

Exhibit 1
[image]

Exhibit 2
[image]

Comment: Once the goop comes out, it's time for a new one.

Comment: Smoke and goop, both signs of electronic death, it's dead.

Comment: Replacing the capacitor was indeed needed, however, it turns out that the breaker in the main breaker box (not the outside cutoff) was defective and needed replacing as well. I suspect that one took out the other (breaker the capacitor, or capacitor the breaker). Hopefully, having both be new will help, and glad I found an "open to the public" HVAC supply store open on Saturday!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capacitor needs replacement.  While it is possible there is a circuitry problem causing the capacitor to overheat (and thus fail like this), it is also possible it was simply time for this electrolytic capacitor to fail while nothing else is wrong.

See [this photo](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Blown_up_electrolytic_capacitor.jpg) for a similar failure mode.

Comment: It's only about 2 years old, but at the same time as it's gone out, there was a light flicker. Now we need to determine whether the flicker was caused by the capacitor, or the capacitor failure by the cause of the flicker.

Comment: @Hugo:  That's unfortunately new.  It is new enough to expect many more years of trouble-free service, but old enough for the warranty to have expired.

Comment: Very true @wallyk. I suspect the batch may have been bad, since that was the second replacement (back then) within a few days, as the first one went out (failed after running 20-30 minutes) the day it was replaced. So one bad "out of the box", other one blows within 2 years? At least these new ones are different brand, and made in Feb this year, so probably not the same batch!